# What is the meaning of the term "Kamakrazee" in the movie Mad Max:Fury Road?

Tags: dialogue, mad-max-fury-road

In Mad Max: Fury Road, the term "Kamakrazee" was used three times.
During the scene where Ace loads the War Rig, we hear the following chant:

> "We are war boys!"
>
> "War boys!"
>
> "Kamakrazee war boys!"
>
> "War boys! "
>
> "Fucacima kamakrazee war boys!"

This led me to believe that the term "Kamakrazee" is a heavily mispronounced version of the word "Kamikaze", fused with "crazy". This makes sense, considering some other words have received the same treatment in the Mad Max universe (Fucacima, Guzzoline, traited, etc.) We also get to see the War Boys conducting a Kamikaze attack in the film.

However, in the scene where Nux (Nicholas Hoult) enters the War Rig and tries to throttle Furiousa (Charlize Theron), the following dialogue happens:

> Nux: "You traited him!"
>
> (Attempts to strangle Furiosa, but is thrown aside quickly. Furiosa lunges forward and points a knife at Nux)
>
> Wife 1: "No unnecessary killing!"
>
> Furiosa: "This War Boy wants me dead!"
>
> Wife 2: "We agreed!"
>
> **Wife 3: "He's kamakrazee!"**
>
> Wife 4: "He's just a kid at the end of his half-life!"
>
> Nux: "No! I live, I die, I live again!"

(Unfortunately, most of this is pieced together from memory, since I can't seem to remember which wife said which, and that it's impossible to find a script for the movie online. I'd appreciate it if someone could correct this for me, since I'm unable to watch the movie right now.)

The term "Kamikaze" would make no sense in this context. So what would the wife in question mean by "Kamakrazee"? And why is she using it as a reason not to kill Nux?

Comment: I think wife 3 is on Furiosa's side. #3 thinks that he's dangerous, suicidal and may put everyone's lives in danger, now #4 starts defending him by saying that he's just a boy.

Comment: At the wiki http://madmax.wikia.com/wiki/War_Boys you can read that "They were based on the Japanese Kamikaze pilots of World War II". So i guess its just like Alexandru wrote...

Comment: @chaitanya89 That seems like the most logical explanation.

Comment: Suicidal death wish type of crazy. So crazy they will do something even if it will kill them. How does that not sense in that context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kama is a japanese weapon, and the term Kamacrazy was used on Urban Dictionary in 2011 to describe "Crazy to the extent that you'd practically go running out in tribal-wear swinging a kama (sickle) at civilians, not because you are an overall angry person but just for the simple fact that you've probably been bored to the point where your sanity has been weakened."

But that is still very similar seeing as both describe it as going into battle, regardless of possible death... also, both stem from japan.

Comment: I wouldn't know about using urban dictionary as a source of information, but this is certainly a much better answer than the other one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will find an explanation that is based on facts.
The speculation that makes some sense and has some logic behind it is that:
`kamakrazee= kamikaze + crazy`.

It's not uncommon for people to come up with new words (selfie, bae...). Try not to overthink movies...

Comment: I'm not finding the word itself strange, I have addressed what I find about it in question. As for overthinking movies, hmm, if only there was a stack devoted to just that...

Comment: Still my answer makes sense :). Why would you kill a brainwashed kid (because that's what he basically is), when you can "open his eyes". They are kamikaze because that's how they are thought to live, they are easy to manipulate and easily replaced.